# Calculating the Most Reduced Sets in a Set of Sets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algebraic-combinatorics

I'm having trouble solving this problem efficiently:

Let's say we have the following sets

`{1, 2, 3}
{1, 2}
{2, 3}
{1}`

We want to eliminate those sets which are supersets of other sets. For example, `{1}` is a subset of both `{1, 2, 3}` and `{1, 2}`, so those two would be eliminated. Likewise, `{2, 3}` is a subset of `{1, 2, 3}` so could also eliminate it. After these elimination operations are complete we would be left with the following:

`{2, 3}
{1}`

It is important to note that the span of the union of all sets doesn't need to be preserved, and should `{2, 3}` have been replaced with `{2}`, it also would have eliminated `{1, 2, 3}`, leaving only `{1}` and `{2}`.

For the problem I'm working on I have to find the most reduced sets for 4 billion sets (let's call these sets $S$), where each set in $S$ could contain anywhere from 1 to 32 sets, resulting in a possible 66 billion comparisons.

Is there a way to use mathematics to model these sets to make it more efficient to run?

**EDIT**

For clarification, the nesting of the sets can be represented as follows:

`{
  {
    {1, 2, 3}
    {1, 2}
    {2, 3}
    {1}
  },
  {
    {1, 2}
    {1}
  },
  ...
}`

The first **nested** layer in this representation represents $S$, and the sets within each set in $S$ are represented by second nested layer. In this case these are the sets with numbers in them.

Comment: 'Each set in $S$ could contain anywhere from 1 to 32 sets' .... Do you mean 1 to 32 elements? And these 32 are out of how many possibilities? Or can we not make any assumptions about the nature of these 1 to 32 elements?

Comment: @Bram28 Sorry, I edited it to make a clarification. Let me know if you are still confused. Thanks!

Comment: OK, so $S$ is a set of sets $S_i$ of sets $S_ij$ of numbers ... And your task is to reduce each set $S_i$ as much as possible? So in your example, $S_1$ gets reduced to $\{\{2,3\},\{1\}\}$ and $S_2$ to $\{\{1\}\}$? So are there any relationships between the sets $S_i$ that might inform the reduction of $S_j$ given the reduction of $S_i$? Because if not, don't we just have the problem of reducing a single set of sets of numbers ... But a bunch of times?

Comment: That's right. It's not a hard problem to solve instance by instance. Solving it efficiently without the computation taking days is the tough part. I know this is probably an implementation issue, not a maths issue, but I wanted to ask on here to see if there was any magical form of tackling this I was unaware of.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Now, can anything be assumed about the nature of the 1 to 32 sets?

Comment: For those, the size of the set ranges from 1-32 sets. The size of each set within that ranges from 1-5 elements, and and the values of the elements can range from 0-4, restricted to integers.

Comment: Ah! That certainly restricts things, so there are probably some ways to exploit that.  Do you know beforehand how many sets there are? E.g. If you are told that some set has 32 sets, then you can immediately say that the reduced set will have to be $\{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\}\}$ without looking at the sets of this set at all.

Comment: Wait!  Your 4 billion sets are all the possible sets you can create this way, right? OK, so then we can analytically figure out what the end result will be, without having to actually do any reductions!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49786/discussion-between-robert-and-bram28).

Comment: I added an algorithm that I think is pretty efficient to generate your desired set.

Comment: This is more than I could have asked for! Thank you much Bram!

Comment: You're welcome! Coming up with the algorithm was fun. Also, fiven the nature of the algrithm you should be able to calculate $|SSS_n|$ for any $n$ fairly easily. I did this very quickly on the back of an envelope (as in: Don't trust me on this .. I could easily have miscounted somewhere ...) and got to $|SSS_4| =371, i.e. The eventual set you are looking for will have 371+2=373 irreducible sets of sets.

Comment: Huh! Very interesting! I will implement it tomorrow in code to check it for $|SSS_4| and $|SSS_5|, and it should significantly reduce the time necessary to compute what I need. Fun fact: For $|SSS_4| the algorithm would have ran in 2 seconds, $|SSS_5| 40 hours, and $|SSS_6| 10^18 years using the old approach. Thank god that's gone.

Comment: $SSS_4$ in 2 seconds? Remember, that's for the one with elements 0 through 4, i.e. the one that you asked about with 4+ billion sets of sets ... it would have been able do that in 2 seconds?

Comment: Ahh, no. $SSS_4$ would have been the set from 0-3 (4 elements long). $SSS_5$ would have been 0-4 (5 elements long)

Comment: OK, so your original approach would have taken 40 hours! Yeah, 2 seconds didn't sound right for that! Well, it'll be 2 seconds now ... probably less than that even!

Comment: Were you able to implement the algorithm?  I calculated the numbers a litttle more carefully: as shown in the post, $|SSS_0| =1$, $|SSS_1|=4$, $|SSS_2|=15$, and then I get $|SSS_3|= 66$, $|SSS_4|=373$, and $|SSS_5|=2824$. Adding 2 gives the total number of irreducible sets, so your desired set will have 375 irreducible sets.

Comment: I've been working on implementing it the past few days. I came across some cases that are still irreducible, but aren't covered by this algorithm. In particular for |$SSS_2$|, it doesn't create {{0, 2}, {0, 1}} or {{0, 1}, {1, 2}}. This is because the previous set needed to create that would be {{0, 1}, {0}} and {{0, 1}, {1}}, which doesn't exist for |$SSS_1$| since those are reducible. Currently thinking about ways to tackle this.

Comment: Also I found the academic terms for these types of problems. They're technically called binary matrices, zero-one matrices, or boolean matrices. The set theory stuff I posted here is simply those matrices in set representation by including the indexes of all 1's in each row of a matrix. Each row represents an $S$, and each matrix represents an $SS$

Comment: FYI I created a new question with a different approach, since it may be answer to generate these via a matrix approach than a set approach: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054538/generate-all-non-covered-boolean-matrices-with-n-rows

Comment: Oh darn, yes, my approach does miss out on some sets! Thanks for pointing this out.  Hmm, I wonder if the whole idea of generating $SSS_{n+1}$ from $SSS_n$ is shot ... Ok, back to the drawing board!  Are you having any luck?

Comment: I updated my algorithm ... hopefully it is still of some use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking at all $2^{32}$ possible sets of sets of 5 different elements, that means that the end result will be the set of all irreducible sets of sets of those elements: every such an irreducible set will be in the original set, and hence will end up in the resulting set, and every reducible set will reduce to one of those irreducible sets.

So, rather than starting with all 4+ billion sets of sets and doing that crazy number of comparisons, there is in fact no need to go through the actual reductions at all! It is really just a manner of figuring out all those irreducible sets of sets!

**Addition**

When I say it is 'just' a matter of figuring out all those irreducible sets of sets I do not mean that that is a trivial task  ... In fact, coming up with an algorithm that systematically generates all those sets will still require some thinking, and some algorithms to do this will be more efficient than others (indeed, coming up with an efficient algorithm is an interesting problem in and of itself). But, whatever way you come up with, I'm sure it'll be a heck of a lot more efficient than doing the actual reductions!

**Addition 2**

OK, so here is a sketch of an algorithm I came up with:

Define $SSS(S)$ relative to some set $S$ of elements to be the set of sets of elements occurring in $S$ that contains all the irreducible sets of sets of those elements, with the exception of the empty sets of sets, and the set containing only the empty set. In other words, $SSS(\{0,1,2,3,4\})$ (which I'll abbreviate to $SSS_4$ is what we're eventually after once we include those last two sets. But as it turns out, the more general $SSS(S)$ is handy to work with for the algorithm given any set $S$.

Algorithm:

Start with a set of sets of sets $SSS_0 = \{\{\{0\}\}\}$.

Now loop where for any $n$, create $SSS_{n+1}$ from $SSS_n$ as follows:

A. First, add $\{\{n+1\}\}$ to $SSS_{n+1}$

Then, for each $SS \in SSS_n$:

B. Add $SS \cup \{\{n+1\}\}$ to $SSS_{n+1}$

C. 'Extend' every $S \in SS$ with $n+1$ to form a set $SSS_{S,n+1}$ of sets of sets of elements, take the 'çross-product' of all such generated $SSS_i$, and add the resulting sets to $SSS_{n+1}$.

By 'extending' $S$ with $m$ to form $S_m$ I mean the following operation:

C1. If $S = \{ x \}$ for some single element $x$, then $SSS_{S,m} = \{\{\{x\}\},\{\{x,n\}\}\}$. Add this to final result and stop

C2. If $S$ contains two or more elements, figure out $SSS(S)$.

C3. Remove $\{S\}$ from this set. Call this $SSS1$

C4. Add $m$ to each of the $S' \in SS \in SSS1$. Call this $SSS2$

C5. Add $S$ to each $SS \in SSS2$. Call this $SSS3$

C6. Add $\{S\}$ and $\{ S + m \}$ to $SSS3$ and add all this to final result.

By taking a 'cross-product' $SSS_1 \times SSS_2 \times ... \times SSS_n$ of sets I mean something akin to the Cartesian product: find all tuplets with one element from $SSS_1$, one from $SSS_2$, etc.  except that instead of making this into a tuple, the elements should be unioned into one new set. And yes, make sure to regard these as operations on sets, since you can get multiple copies of the same set during this process.

Finally, when you have reached the desired $n$, add $\{\}$ (the empty sets of sets) and $\{\{\}\}$ to $SSS_n$, and that will be set of all irreducible sets of sets of integers $0$ through $n$.

Example:

What is $SSS_2$?

OK, start with $SSS_0 = \{\{\{0\}\}\}$

Then for $SSS_1$ we get:

A. First, add $\{\{1\}\}$

There is only one set $SS \in SSS_0$, and that is $\{\{0\}\}$, so:

B. Add $\{\{0\}\} \cup \{\{1\}\} = \{\{0\},\{1\}\}$ to $SSS_1$

C1. $SSS_{\{0\},1\}} = \{\{\{0\}\},\{\{0,1\}\}\}$.

So: $SSS_1$ = $\{\{\{1\}\},\{\{0\},\{1\}\},\{\{0\}\},\{\{0,1\}\}\}$

Moving on to $SSS_2$:

A. Add $\{\{2\}\}$

B. Adding $\{2\}$ to all $SS \in SSS$, we get $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$, $\{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\}\}$, $\{\{0\},\{2\}\}$, and $\{\{0,1\},\{2\}\}$.

C.

Extending $\{0\}$ with $2$ we get $\{\{\{0\}\},\{\{0,2\}\}\}$.

Likewise, extending $\{1\}$ with $2$ we get $\{\{\{1\}\},\{\{1,2\}\}\}$.

For $\{\{0\},\{1\}\}$ we take the cross-product of $\{\{\{0\}\},\{\{0,2\}\}\}$ and $\{\{\{1\}\},\{\{1,2\}\}\}$, giving us: $\{\{0\},\{1\}\}$, $\{\{0,2\},\{1\}\}$, $\{\{0\},\{1,2\}\}$, and $\{\{0,2\},\{1,2\}\}$

Finally, for $\{\{0,1\}\}$ we get:

C2. $SSS(\{0,1\}) = \{\{\{1\}\},\{\{0\},\{1\}\},\{\{0\}\},\{\{0,1\}\}\}$

C3. Remove $\{\{0,1\}\}$ so we get $\{\{\{1\}\},\{\{0\},\{1\}\},\{\{0\}\}\}$

C4. Add $2$ to all sets: $\{\{\{1,2\}\},\{\{0,2\},\{1,2\}\},\{\{0,2\}\}\}$

C5. Add  $\{0,1\}$ to all sets of sets: $\{\{\{0,1\},\{1,2\}\},\{\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{1,2\}\},\{\{0,1\},\{0,2\}\}\}$

C6. Finally, add $\{\{0,1\}\}$ and $\{\{0,1,2\}\}$

Putting all these together, we get:

$SSS_2 = \{\{\{2\}\},\{\{1\},\{2\}\},\{\{0\},\{1\},\{2\}\}, \{\{0\},\{2\}\},\{\{0,1\},\{2\}\},\{\{0\}\}, \{\{0,2\}\},\{\{1\}\},\{\{1,2\}\}, \{\{0\},\{1\}\}, \{\{0,2\},\{1\}\}, \{\{0\},\{1,2\}\}, \{\{0,1\},\{1,2\}\},\{\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{1,2\}\},\{\{0,1\},\{0,2\}\},\{\{0,1\}\}, \{\{0,1,2\}\} \}$

OK, two more iterations, and you have $SSS_4$, and then add $\{\}$ and $\{\{\}\}$ to that to get your desired set. That's it!