# Generate all Non-Covered Boolean Matrices with N rows

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I am attempting to generate all non-covered (or irreducible) boolean (or binary, zero-one, etc.) matrices for a given $n$ columns.

For instance, given $n$ = 2, the possible non-covered boolean matrices are the following:

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Is anyone fimiliar with research in this area and know how to easily generate this for any given $n$ columns?

If it is useful, it is also possible to encode these into sets via translating the matrices into sets or vice versa. The following is a translation of $n$ = 2 non-covered boolean matrices:

{0, 1}

{0}

{1}

{0}, {1}

**EDIT**

The concept of **covering** can be explained in the following approaches:

Matrix Approach:

A row $M_1$ in matrix $M$ is **covered** by another row $M_2$ if all elements $M_{1i}$ which have the value of $1$ also exist in $M_{2}$, and $M_{1}$ != $M_{2}$

Covered Example: 
If we have the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is **covered** by $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Uncovered Example:

In the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, neither row **covers** the other, so it is an **uncovered** matrix.

Set Approach:

A set $S_1$ in $S$ is **covered** if another set $S_2$ in $S$ is a strict subset of $S_1$.

Covered Example:

If $S$ = {{0, 1, 2}, {1, 2}}, {0, 1, 2} is **covered** by {1, 2}

Uncovered Example:

If $S$ = {{0, 1}, {0, 2}}, $S_1$ is not covered by $S_2$ since neither are a strict subset of the other.

Comment: I updated the post to explain covering. Hopefully it is a good explanation. Let me know if it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why don't you also consider column "covering?" (What you call "covering" is also known as "dominance.")

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking to generate all the antichains in the power set lattice.  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Antichain.html .  They include the empty set, while you seem not to.  If n>6 you will likely have trouble generating them all.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi I am using this for theoretical research on a machine learning algorithm, and the rows represent possible hypothesis classes, so I don't think column covering/dominance doesn't make sense in this aspect.

Comment: @deinst This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you!

Comment: So, each column corresponds to a hypothesis?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi Columns correspond to example data points. Rows are possible hypothesis classes